# Вылетает ошибка: "WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:12345/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED""

Tags: javascript, python

Всем привет, я новичок и делаю по Ютубу простой чат, но столкнулся с проблемой: вылетает вот такая ошибка в панеле разработчиков: "websocket_client.js:4 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:12345/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Вот мой код (Питон-файл):

```
import asyncio

import websocket

all_clients = []


async def send_message(message: str):
    for client in all_clients:
        await client.send(message)




async def new_client_connected(client_socket: websocket.WebSocketClientProtocol, path: str):
    print("New user connected")
    all_clients.append(client_socket)

    while True:
        new_message = await client_socket.recv()
        print("New message from a user", new_message)
        await send_message(message=new_message)

async def start_server():
    await websocket.serve(new_client_connected, "localhost", 12345)


if __name__=='__main__':
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    event_loop.run_until_complete(start_server())
    event_loop.run_forever()
```

и (JS-файл):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){


    let websocketClient = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:12345");

    websocketClient.onopen = () => {
        console.log("Client conntected!");
        websocketClient.send("Hello!");
    };

    


}, false);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: у websocket нет метода WebSocketClientProtocol. он есть в библиотеке websockets

Comment: @bilal , спасибо за ответ, а зачем питон-файл еще запускать отдельно? Я думал он должен сразу работать после f5?

Comment: Да, можно через F5 - Запуск кода

Answer (score -1, accepted):

У websocket нет метода WebSocketClientProtocol. Он есть в библиотеке websockets.
Используй библиотеку websockets вместо websocket

```
pip install websockets
```

и замени везде websocket на websockets.
Запускаешь код `python название_файла.py`

UPD Какой-то чел поставил просто минус без комментария. Пруфы что работает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Смысл кому-то помогать если ставят минус без объяснения